# facebook oauth token getting expired for some users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Why does the facebook token expire and I am seeing it for some people and some not. I am using the below scope

```
public static string _FacebookExtendedPermissions = "user_about_me,publish_stream,read_stream,user_photos";
```

Do I need to add something more? Heard that "offline_access" has been deprecated.

Thanks
Sujit

Comment: read the section `Avoiding OAuthException` in this [tutorial](http://www.thepcwizard.in/2013/02/working-with-facebook-c--sharp-sdk.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution. You can extend your token for 60 days by the below code

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&fb_exchange_token=SHORT_LIVED_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

thanks.
Sujit